# Documentation for the Office 365 JSON-interface for web applications

Tags: office365, reverse-engineering

The Office 365 (hosted version) has a JSON-based interface for JavaScript apps running in the web browser to access the Office 365 data. This is how Microsoft's web interface gets information from the back end.

This interface is different from the GraphQL API. Instead of using an Access Token, it uses the user's browser authentication credentials. In particular, the following HTTP headers are required in the POST message:

- Cookie
- X-OWA-CANARY
- X-OWA-CorrelationId
- X-OWA-SessionId
- X-OWA-UserPostData
- X-Req_Source
- Action

To get the User's auto-reply message, this URL is accessed with an HTTP POST. For example, to get the mailbox autoreply, one would use this URL:

- https://outlook.office365.com/owa/service.svc?action=GetMailboxAutoReplyConfiguration&EP=1&app=Calendar&n=13&n=25

The body of the post contains:

```
action=GetMailboxAutoReplyConfiguration
EP=1
app=Calendar
n=13
n=25
```

The response is a JSON message that looks like this:

```
{
    "Header": {
        "ServerVersionInfo": {
            "MajorVersion": 15,
            "MinorVersion": 20,
            "MajorBuildNumber": 2856,
            "MinorBuildNumber": 19,
            "Version": "V2018_01_08"
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "CreateOOFEvent": false,
        "OOFEventSubject": "",
        "Recipients": null,
        "ReminderMinutesBeforeStart": -1,
        "ReminderMessage": "",
        "ReminderMessageText": "\r\n",
        "DeclineAllEventsForScheduledOOF": false,
        "DeclineEventsForScheduledOOF": false,
        "AutoDeclineFutureRequestsWhenOOF": true,
        "EventsToDeleteIDs": null,
        "AutoReplyState": 0,
        "EndTime": "2020-03-20T15:00:00Z",
        "ExternalAudience": 0,
        "ExternalMessage": "<html><head><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Exchange Server\">\n<!-- converted from text -->\n<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style></head>\n<body>\n<font size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:11pt;\"><div class=\"PlainText\">I am unable to respond to email. \n</div></span></font>\n</body>\n</html>\n",
        "InternalMessage": "<html><head><meta name=\"Generator\" content=\"Microsoft Exchange Server\">\n<!-- converted from text -->\n<style><!-- .EmailQuote { margin-left: 1pt; padding-left: 4pt; border-left: #800000 2px solid; } --></style></head>\n<body>\n<font size=\"2\"><span style=\"font-size:11pt;\"><div class=\"PlainText\">I am unable to respond to email. Please call my assistant if you need me. \n</div></span></font>\n</body>\n</html>\n",
        "DeclineMeetingMessage": "",
        "ExternalMessageText": "I am unable to respond to email.\r\n",
        "InternalMessageText": "I am unable to respond to email. Please call my assistant if you need me.\r\n",
        "DeclineMeetingMessageText": "\r\n",
        "StartTime": "2020-03-19T15:00:00Z"
    },
    "WasSuccessful": true,
    "ErrorCode": 0,
    "ErrorMessage": null,
    "UserPrompt": null,
    "IsUserError": false
}
```

My question: is there any documentation for this API? (I can't find any.) If not, is there an easy way to collect API information from the browser? It took me 30 minutes to get the information in this post; there must be a faster way.

Comment: I don't think the `owa/service.svc` api is meant for public consumption, I think its just what outlook web app uses to make internal requests, which is why there is a lack of documentation online. I think that if you want to make your own api requests, you should look into the public outlook rest api https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#GetAutoReplySettings

Comment: I can't use the public REST API because it doesn't support SAML. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues "

Comment: hence the `reverse-engineering` tag